# Animating change of content inside of the div with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, redux

I'm fairly new to React and looking for an answer to the following question. I put down only the essential code to understand what i try to accomplish:

Let's say i have a react component like that:

```
class Content extends Component{
render(){
  <div className="container-text">
      {this.props.randomNumber}
  </div>
}
```

Where this.props.randomNumber is coming from Redux state, and basically show's a random number everytime user clicks a button that changes it. How can i create the fade animation everytime the randomNumber changes?

Answer (score 0):

In ***Redux*** you can defined under your class ***Content*** one function ***mapStateToProps*** .

Eg:

```
const mapStateToProps = {randomNumber : yourAction}
```

Then you can connect with ***Redux***:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(Content)
```

Here have not any state => a function ***mapDispatchToProps = null***

Hope it is helpful for you ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need the [CssTransitionGroup](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#high-level-api-reactcsstransitiongroup)

So something like:

```
class Content extends Component{
    render(){
       //key is important as it tells react that the item changed and therefore apply the transition events
       const item = <span key={this.props.randomNumber}>{this.props.randomNumber}</span>; 
       return (
          <div className="container-text"> 
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
              transitionName="example"
              transitionEnterTimeout={500}
              transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
              {item}
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
//in css
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.example-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```